# Permission denied при использование scp

Tags: linux

Выдает ошибку `Permission denied`, когда я пытаюсь скопировать папку на удаленный сервер

Что я вижу:

```bash
stas@stas-S428:~/Рабочий стол$ scp ./lab33 -P 8007 ershov@193.108.113.188:/home/ershov/home
ershov@193.108.113.188's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: проверьте есть ли у пользователя `ershov` права на запись в каталог `/home/ershov/`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод команд `lsattr -d /home/ershov` и `ls -dl /home/ershov` с удаленного сервера

Comment: `ershov@10babe6c01e6:~/home$ lsattr -d /home/ershov
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/ershov`
Вот такое lsattr выводит